# Conversion to clauses

Tags: logic

first things first: English is not my native language and therefore I do not know if the terminology that I use is correct.

A clause is: Some logic statement that only contains OR and NOT. An example would be (NOT p) OR q.

Here are the rules stated in the books for proving some clauses:

1. p OR q
2. NOT p

Conclusion: q

1. p OR q OR r
2. NOT p

C: q or R

1. p OR q
2. NOT p OR r

C: q OR r

I understand why these rules are what they are. The book calls these rules "the resolution principle."

Now, my problem is converting 'regular' logic statements (with AND and what not in them) to clauses and then using the resolution principle to prove the premises.

Could you please point me to some guide that could help me understand this? Or could you please solve the following example and try to go into detail of how you solve it?

Here's my example:

1. p -> q
2. p OR q OR r
3. r

Conclusion: q

Truth table for -> : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Logical_implication

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a guide:

- $p$ AND $q$ is handled by making two clauses, one for $p$ and one for $q$
- $p \to q$ is (NOT $p$) OR $q$
- NOT ( $p$ AND $q$) is (NOT $p$) OR (NOT $q$)
- NOT ( $p$ OR $q$) is (NOT $p$) AND (NOT $q$)

For more complicated expressions, apply those rules recursively, along with De Morgan's law and the distributive laws. Basically, you put the formula into [conjunctive normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) and then split that into one clause for each conjunct.

In your example, I think (3) should be (NOT r), because as it is stated all three formulas are true if $r$ is true and $p,q$ are false.  If we make that change, we have

1. (NOT $p$) OR $q$
2. $p$ OR $q$ OR $r$
3. (NOT $r$)

From these, you can derive $q$ with two applications of resolution.